# Why does Red John never attack Jane directly like his other victims?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-mentalist

I have just finished watching S03E03 of The Mentalist, where Red John leaves Kristina Frye in a hypnotised(?) state. According to Jane, Kristina was targeted because she talked about Red John in the TV show.

If this is true then, why does Red John never attack Jane directly (Jane too spoke about him in the TV show)? He attacks Jane's family, anyone close to him (according to Jane), leaves clues so that Jane takes those cases but never hits him directly (I don't know if he will later in the episodes). Is there a reason to that?

Comment: I always thought that Red John was continuing to torture Jane by NOT attacking him but rather killing other innocents.

Comment: Is there any reason behind him doing so? I mean, he always killed his victims. Why he chose to behave differently with Jane?

Comment: He killed Jane's family for calling him out so Jane *continues* to be a victim by Red John killing more people....hence "torture". Red John maintains his revenge that way.

Comment: It feels like he wants to show off to Jane, but not to any police dept, like he has been challenged by Jane. But both Kristina and Jane did the same offence. Then he could have also tortured Kristina iin the same way as he did with Jane, but he mentally killed her.

Comment: Oh okay..I might have missed that Jane challenged him.

Comment: Plot armour. Jane has to continually play cat & mouse with Red John, otherwise the series has no long plot. idk whether they ever did have a final showdown (though one would imagine they would if the series was allowed to run to a full conclusion), I drifted off after about season 5.

Comment: At the midpoint of season six, the Red John case is solved...so you missed it.. @Tetsujin

Comment: @Paulie_D that solve on Red John is worse than ending of the Lost.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, it was never Red John's plan to just kill Jane.

I think, Jane was the first person that presented a challenge to him in an intelectual level. But at the time Jane was only a fake embarrassing acting the part on TV. Red John saw potential in  him and instead of killing him, made sure of making him suffer by killing his family instead.

From that point they just started to play this game, with Red John always escaping or dissapearing as Jane got closer. Red John was always one or two steps forwards. But Jane wasnt too far behind, and I think Red John found excitement in their game. So he kept it up, knowing one day, when Jane stopped being entertaining or get too close to him for comfort, it would be then and only then, he would finally kill Jane.